# error 126: Could not open Dll "python34.dll"

Tags: python, delphi

Using Delphi 10.3 I have installed the new python4delphi package after making some minor source changes to get it to compile and install. The Demo programs load and compile OK but when I run a demo an error 126: Could not open Dll "python34.dll" appears. I have downloaded a few different copies and placed them in windows\system32 but I get the same result each time.

When I run regsvr32 python34.dll (as administrator) I get a failed to load error.

What am I missing here?

Putting the dll in syswow64 changed things.
It fails in the create form when it gets to:

```
*procedure TPythonEngine.DoOpenDll(const aDllName : string);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  if UseLastKnownVersion then
    for i:= Integer(COMPILED_FOR_PYTHON_VERSION_INDEX) downto 1 do
    begin
      RegVersion := PYTHON_KNOWN_VERSIONS[i].RegVersion;
      inherited DoOpenDll(PYTHON_KNOWN_VERSIONS[i].DllName);
      if IsHandleValid then
      begin
        DllName := PYTHON_KNOWN_VERSIONS[i].DllName;
        APIVersion := PYTHON_KNOWN_VERSIONS[i].APIVersion;
        Exit;
      end;
    end
  else
    RegVersion := GetPythonVersionFromDLLName(aDllName);
  inherited;
end;*
```

It steps through the compiled versions until it hit 3.4 and fails the IsHandleValid test.

If I run regsvr32 python34.dll an error is returned "python34.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Drilling down further it is

```
*Py_Initialize:      procedure; cdecl;*
```

in the PythonEngine that fails.

Using python38.dll I got the same results.

Comment: Do you have Windows x64 installed? Then a x86 (or 32 bit) DLL has to be placed in ``Windows\SysWOW64\``!

Comment: The other way around could be: Do you create a 64 bit app? Then you need a 64 bit Python DLL, placed in Windows\System32\ (on Windows x64, of course)

Comment: No, you really don't want to copy these files to the system directory. As a rule, don't ever modify the system directory.

Comment: You may try to trace the access with Process Monitor : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/downloads/procmon. Just remember that with a 32 (/64) bits target compilation in Delphi you need a 32 (/64) bits DLL.